# Can a doubly stochastic matrix be asymmetric?

Tags: matrices, markov-chains, stochastic-matrices

It's a fairly simple question but I cannot find the answer to it anywhere.

Comment: It’d be great if you could include the definitions of ‘doubly stochastic’ and ‘asymmetric’. :)

Comment: @Haskell, "doubly stochastic" means all the row sums and all the column sums are 1; "asymmetric" means not symmetric, that is, not equal to its transpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$${1\over15}\pmatrix{8&1&6\cr3&5&7\cr4&9&2\cr}$$

Comment: It occurs to me that a simpler answer would be $$\pmatrix{0&1&0\cr0&0&1\cr1&0&0\cr}$$

Answer (score 1):

For more examples, one can do no better than $n$-by-$n$ *[circulant matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix)*; for instance, if $a$, $b$, and $c$ are nonnegative numbers such that $a+b+c=1$, then the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c \\
c & a & b \\
b & c & a 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is doubly stochastic and not symmetric.